# Dependencies no longer available in init or other controller defined functions

Tags: angularjs, undefined, angularjs-controller

I have the following simple module definition:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$q', function ($scope, $q) {           
     debugger; //checkpoint 1
     $scope.init = function () {
         debugger; //checkpoint 2
     }
}])
```

When the execution hits the `debugger;` at `checkpoint 1`, I can see that all the dependencies (`$q` and others, not shown for brevity) are defined. However, when the `init` function is called (`checkpoint 2`), all the dependencies, except the `$scope`, are undefined. I use the same exact structure in other modules and I proofed trivial stuff such as spelling and directives.

I've run out of ideas for where to continue my search for errors. What unsuspecting *quirks* should I look for? What can be the problem here?

Comment: Unless you use the dependencies in the code, in init method, debugger would not show then. Use them and they would appear.

Comment: @Chandermani, now that's just plain old silly. You were right, once I referenced the dependency, it was _magically_ there. Is that a `AngularJS` feature? I'm confused...

Comment: No this is JS. Remember you are calling a function defined inside another function, and closure does not get created till you use the variable from parent.